# Npm run dev no funciona Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nodejs, npm

Al ejecutar npm run dev me da los siguientes errores

> ✖ Mix
> Compiled with some errors in 652.43ms

> ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):

> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):

He probado a borrar la carpeta laravel-mix y hacer un npm install pero sin resultados

`resources/css/app.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import 'custom.css';
@import 'test.css';
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```html
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes mostrar lo que tienes en tu archivo `webpack.mix.js`? ¿Cambiaste algo en el archivo `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Otra cosa, intenta quitar las 3 líneas de `@tailwind` y luego compila, me dices si eso hace que los errores no aparezcan

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con lo que tengo en webpack.mix.js

Comment: He probado a quitar  tailwind en el archivo app.css pero da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay problemas reportados con la combinación de versiones de los siguientes módulos ([Reporte de errores](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/2471))

```
tailwind
node
postcss-loader
postcss-importer
postcss
laravel-mix
```

Primero revisa las versiones que tiene cada uno de esos componentes, si alguna versión es menor a las mostradas a continuación entonces esa podría ser la que está afectando

```
     "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
     "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11", 
     "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
     "postcss": "^8.2.1",
     "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
     "postcss-loader": "^4.2.0",
     "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.2.1",
```

Intenta primero actualizar `laravel-mix` ([Guía completa](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade))

```
npm install laravel-mix@latest
```

Si eso no soluciona el problema intenta actualizar node ([Guía completa](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version))

Si eso no soluciona el problema entonces baja la versión de `postcss-loader` (Esta sería la peor opción en mi opinion)

```
npm uninstall postcss-loader --save-dev
npm install postcss-loader@~3.0.0 --save-dev
```